# How to insert a new line after completing a script in vscode on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

When working in vscode on Linux how do you insert a newline after running a c++ file in the integrated terminal?  In the photo the first run is run as normal and the second run I inserted a newline at the end of the code.

I'd like it so after testing something in the terminal the terminal starts at the next line instead of on top of my code.

[image: Example]

Comment: Doesn't happen for me.  What does your code look like?

Comment: If you mean making your prompt appear on a new line regardless of whether your program output ended with a newline character, then that's a shell-specific thing. Some shells such as fish and (IIRC) zsh do this by default. If you want to do it for bash, you can probably use https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60469.

Comment: @TylerTian Thank you that worked perfectly.  That's exactly what I meant just didn't know how to explain it properly or look it up with correct terminology.

Comment: @TylerTian Time to make your comment an answer I suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

I am rewriting the answer by @Tyler:

> If you mean making your prompt appear on a new line regardless of
> whether your program output ended with a newline character, then
> that's a shell-specific thing. Some shells such as fish and (IIRC) zsh
> do this by default. If you want to do it for bash, you can probably
> use https://www.unix.stackexchange.com/a/60469

Beside this. Some IDE also provide configurabl built-in output panel.